# Getting java.io.IOException: Error: doesn't contain version info using pdfbox box dependency 2.0.25

Tags: java, selenium, testing, exception, pdfbox

I am reading pdf data with pdfbox dependency it worked fine in local but while running from jenkins(VM) i am getting this error:

java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Your file is likely empty, or not a PDF.

Comment: 2345666_aad_C99_M12_run.pdf- this is pure pdf url i am trying open

Comment: Then try to find out what is fed to PDFBox. Likely something different than "in local". The next step would be to find out why.